# BFS cycle detection

Tags: graph-algorithm, pseudocode, breadth-first-search, cycle-detection

Could someone provide a step by step pseudocode using BFS to search a cycle in a directed/undirected graph?

Can it get O(|V|+|E|) complexity?

I have seen only DFS implementation so far.

Comment: Why do you want to use BFS ? Do you have to ?
If not, read this, you might prefer using DFS : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869647/why-dfs-and-not-bfs-for-finding-cycle-in-graphs

Comment: @kazu I want to see how it is implemented because my implementation is screwed up.

Comment: Do you just need to know whether a cycle exists or do you need to extract the specific circle itself?

Comment: @Codor just existence I will try to extract myself (but if you can provide that also it will be great).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a *non-recursive* DFS algorithm for detecting cycles in undirected graphs where you replace the stack for the nodes by a queue to get a BFS algorithm. It's straightforward:

```
q <- new queue // for DFS you use just a stack
append the start node of n in q
while q is not empty do
    n <- remove first element of q
    if n is visited
        output 'Hurray, I found a cycle'
    mark n as visited
    for each edge (n, m) in E do
        append m to q
```

Since BFS visits each node and each edge only once, you have a complexity of *O*(|V|+|E|).

Comment: What is a non-recursive DFS? Could you provide pseudocode? I tried implementing but could not make it work.

Comment: thank you. Do we have to use queue? how do you print?

Comment: Yes, for BFS you have to use a queue. Note, this is pseudo code. There is no printing. The output statement says that the algorithm has reached a special state. This _may_ be printing in a real implementation.

Comment: let me think about it. if i have trouble getting to print I will update.

Comment: I don't think works. Consider a case where there are two paths to the same node. Just because you visited it before, doesn't make it a cycle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869661/986067

Comment: This only words for cycle detections in undirected graphs. With directed graphs it produces false positives.

Comment: @vcovo Yes, you're right. I'll update my description.

Answer (score 2):

I find BFS algorithm perfect for that.
Time complexity is the same.

You want something like this(Edited from Wikipedia):

```
Cycle-With-Breadth-First-Search(Graph g, Vertex root):

    create empty set S
    create empty queue Q      

    root.parent = null
    Q.enqueueEdges(root)                      

    while Q is not empty:

        current = Q.dequeue()

        for each node n that is adjacent to current:
            if n is not in S:
                add n to S
                n.parent = current
                Q.enqueue(n)
            else  //We found a cycle
                n.parent = current
                return n and current
```

I added only the else its a cycle block for the cycle detection and removed the original if reached target block for target detection. In total it's the same algorithm.

To find the exact cycle you will have to find a common ancestor for n and current. The lowest one is available in O(n) time. Than the cycle is known. ancestor to n and current. current and n are connected.

For more info about cycles and BFS read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464388/6782134